# Automatically generated summation region

Tags: summation

In a multiple `Sum` I need to put an automatically generated summation region.
But when I generate the summation region automatically I get a list whose elements are lists. Then the summation does not work.

For example:

```
Sum[1,{i,1,2},{j,1,2}]
```

works;

```
Sum[1,{{i,1,2},{j,1,2}}]
```

or

```
A = Table[{i[j],j+1},{j,2}];
Sum[1,A]
```

doesn't work.

Comment: You could use something like `Sum[1,Evaluate[Sequence@@{{i,1,2},{j,1,2}}]]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As always there are several possibilities. For example

```
Sum[1,Evaluate[Sequence@@{{i,1,2},{j,1,2}}]]
```

or

```
Sum[1, ##] & @@ {{i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}}
```

both work.

Answer (score 3):

The syntax for `Sum` is wrong. For multiple sums, you list each summation index as a separate argument, not enclosed in a list. For example, instead of

```
Sum[1,{{i,1,2},{j,1,2}}]
```

you need to write

```
Sum[1, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}]

(* ==> 4 *)
```

To modify your last example,

```
Sum[1,A]
```

you should do this:

```
A = Table[{i, j}, {i, 1, 2}, {j, 1, 2}];
Sum[1, {tuple, Flatten[A, 1]}]

(* ==> 4 *)
```

This assumes that your goal was to have `A` be a list of tuples `i, j`.